# With which versions of GWT does Seam work?

Tags: java, gwt, interop, seam

I recently tried to combine SEAM and GWT in a project - but failed using GWT 1.7.1 and Seam 2.1.2 CR2 and Seam 2.2.0 GA ([if you have any ideas why - here is the post](http://www.seamframework.org/Community/SeamGWT17)).

I was wondering: Do you have any experiences which versions of GWT work with which version of SEAM out of the box? With workarounds?

Thx!
(PS: For Seam < 2.1.0 and GWT 1.5, I found [this article describing a workaround](http://www.vierundsechzig.de/blog/?p=184))

Comment: Seam and GWT... sounds like it'd be like an explosion in a complexity factory....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I found out so far:

The problem lies somewhere in the GWTAdapter that Seam 2.x provides. Workaround: Don't rely on the Seam resource servlet (as described [here](http://docs.jboss.org/seam/2.1.2/reference/en-US/html/gwt.html)), but expose your GWT servlets like any other servlet. This means you can't really benefit from all the Seam features inside the servlet, but you can still access your Seam components by retrieving them through a Seam context.

Comment: Good job, wilth (+1) I will study Seam / GWT and Seam / Wicket Seam / Spring integration. I Think The key is up to Seam Context Filter, which is not enabled by default. With regard to skaffman (Spring user - I also use Spring - Spring-MVC) comment, do not worry. He must learn a lot about how Seam internals works. Maybe he could change his opinion